# Broadcast receiver for enabling mobile connection does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to write a `BroadcastReceiver` for checking Internet connection. But it doesn't work. My receiver is:

```
public class MobileDataOnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Broadcast received");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LoadPictureService.class);
        context.startService(intent1);
    }
}
```

When I try to register it dynamically in `MainActivity`, I get "`Cannot resolve symbol conn`": [image]

When I try to register it in a `Manifest`, `BroadcastReceiver` just doesn't start at all. My `Manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aleksandr.homework3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MobileDataOnBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

There are quite a few questions on Stack Overflow on this topic, but no one answers my question. Why can't I register `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically? Why doesn't it work when in `Manifest`? What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the receiver dynamically using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) API, note the second argument is IntentFilter.
You may try the following code

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);   
// this is the constant value android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Also note that if you are targeting API 24 or above then you will not be getting this broadcast that is registered through the manifest entry.

Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html).

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts, even if they have manifest entries to request notification of these events. Apps that are running can still listen for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE on their main thread if they request notification with a BroadcastReceiver.

In general dynamically registered receiver is the way to go for such broadcasts. Just remember to unregsiter them appropriately when your component lifecycle state changes or you no longer need the broadcast.

Comment: For more information check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBjTXKpaFj8